# How to deal with more than one set of radio button groups - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need a little help or suggestion how I can get this to work - I have more that one set of group of radio buttons
The first group checks and unchecks and shows the correct input but when I check the second group the first group is unchecked and the input of the second group is shown.
I want the first group of radio button to not uncheck when the second group of radio is checked. Its strange both of the names groups are different not why it unchecking previous groups. Thought the checked controlled would be better use to tracked when checked. Can any help in solving my problem.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class MainForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isChecked: null,
      isHidden: true,
      selectedOption: null,
      checkedState: null,
    };
  }

  handleCheckboxToggle(name, event) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.setState({
        checkedState: event.target.value,
        isHidden: false,
        selectedOption: event.target.name,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isHidden: true,
        selectedOption: null,
      });
    }
  }

  renderCheckboxComponent(answer) {
    return (
      <div className="form__field--wrapper">
        {
        answer.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={item.id} className="form__checkbox form__checkbox--inline">
            <label className="form__checkbox required" htmlFor={`item.label-${item.name}-${index}`}>
              {item.label}
            </label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              id={`item.label-${item.name}-${index}`}
              name={item.name}
              value={item.value}
              onClick={e => this.handleCheckboxToggle(item.name, e)}
              checked={this.state.checkedState === item.value}
            />
            <span />
          </div>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderFieldInputComponent(fields, name) {
    return (
      <div>
        {
        fields.map(item => (
          this.state.selectedOption === item.name ?
            <div key={item.id} className="form__row">
              <label className="required" htmlFor={name}>
                {item.label}
              </label>
              <input
                type={item.type}
                id={name}
                name={name}
                required
                placeholder={item.placeholder}
              />
              <span />
            </div> : ''
          ))
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    const { isHidden, isChecked } = this.state;
    return (
      <form>
        {
          data.map(item => (
            <div key={item.id} className="form__row form__row--checkbox">
              <p className="form__row--label">{item.name}</p>
              { this.renderCheckboxComponent(item.answer)}
              { !isHidden && this.renderFieldInputComponent(item.field, item.category)}
            </div>
          ))
        }
        <button type="button" className="btn btn--red">Update Preferences</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

MainForm.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number,
    name: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired).isRequired,
};

export default MainForm;
```

This is the data I am working with

```
   {  
  "Questions":[  
    {  
      "id":1,
      "name":"Email",
      "category":"emailPermission",
      "answer":[  
        {  
          "id":10,
          "label":"Yes",
          "value":"emailPermissionYes",
          "name":"emailPermission",
          "checked": true
        },
        {  
          "id":11,
          "label":"No",
          "value":"emailPermissionNo",
          "name":"emailPermission",
          "checked": true
        }
      ],
      "field":[
        {
          "id": 12, 
          "type": "email", 
          "name": "emailPermission", 
          "label": "Enter your email address",
          "placeholder": "example@email.com",
          "required": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {  
      "id":2,
      "name":"Post",
      "category":"postPermission",
      "answer":[  
        {  

          "id": 21,
          "label":"Yes",
          "value":"postPermissionYes",
          "name":"postPermission",
          "checked": true
        },
        {  
          "id": 22,
          "label":"No",
          "value":"postPermissionNo",
          "name":"postPermission",
          "checked": false
        }
      ],
      "field":[
        {
          "id": 23, 
          "type": "text",
          "name": "postPermission", 
          "label": "Postcode", 
          "placeholder": "SE1 7TP",
          "required": true
        }
      ]
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not in how you've handled `name`, but in how you handle the checked state.

Whenever a radio is checked, `this.state.checkedState` changes to the currently selected radio's value.

This means that when one selects a radio button from Question 2, you'll end up with a state similar to `{checkedState: 'postPermissionYes'}`.

When React then re-renders *all* the checkboxes, only the most recently clicked one will pass the `checked={this.state.checkedState === item.value}` test. The previously clicked radio would return false for the `checked={this.state.checkedState === item.value}`.

Instead, I recommend to handle `checkedState` slightly differently…

Store each radio group's value into a state property, you can use the `name` value for each one.

This means that you'd store the state as:

```
this.state = {
    emailPermission: null,
    postPermission: null,
    // other properties would go here as well...
}
```

and your handler would look as follows:

```
handleCheckboxToggle(name, event) {
    this.state[name] = event.target.value;
}
```

lastly, the radio would determine the `checked` attribute as follows:

```
checked={this.state[item.name] === item.value}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it is working now, although I also need to be uncheck the current one, this.setState({ checkedState: this.state[name] = event.target.value, isChecked: this.state[name] = event.target.checked, }); could that work in the same way? –

Comment: Yes, however radio buttons do not normally have the behaviour that they can be “unselected”. What you always can do is add a reset button, which when clicked would set `state.emailPermission` back to `null`.

Comment: Yes, that won't really work with the expectation on the button, will try the isChecked or change to checkbox